# Unsolved many same input -> form to one request / many forms to many requests?

Tags: node.js

There is another post with the same problem with me ,and the solution didnt work for me . So i have code like this :

```
app.post("/updatestatus", (req, res) => {
let id = req.body.id;
let status = req.bo.status;
imgModel.updateMany(
{ _id: { $in: id } },
{ $set: { status: status } },
(err, items) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("An error occurred", err);
  } else {
    res.json({
      code: "200",
      message: "update successfully",
      data: items,
    });
  }
}
);
```

I want to update the status of the inputed id . I also want to update many id at one time, but the code only take 1 id at one time .if i request like this

```
{ "id":"1",
"id:"2"}
```

The id will be duplicated and updated only the one below. Im thinking of using a for loop like this :

```
for ( let i =0, i<= 100, i++){
      let id[i] = req.body.id;
}
```

But it will error because i declared the varible wrong way!How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Javascript object like `req.body` cannot contain the same key twice. If you want multiple values for the key `id`, then `express.urlencoded({extended: false})` will translate the request payload `id=1&id=2` into

```js
req.body = {"id": ["1","2"]}
```

and you can work with the array `req.body.id`.

A request with that payload can be produced with

```html
<form action="/updatestatus" method="post">
  <input name="id"/>
  <input name="id"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

but then the maximal number of `id`s that can be input is fixed (2 in this example).